# Checkmark overlay in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` to do multiple selection by not dismissing the modal, and adding a subview for counting number of selected images.

It is very basic, what I do to show the picker is this:

```
- (IBAction)choseImagesTouched:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    //place image picker on the screen
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

One thing I need, is to add a checkmark to any selected image, like they do in the Photos app when adding to an album.

Can I somehow listen to touch events, get the coordinates and add a subview or overlay view at that location on the screen, to indicate the image has been selected?

Comment: how did you solve this @MartinHN, unfortunately I tried implementing it the same way and now don't know how to show the checkmark overlay.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remember. Not sure if it has become available in newer APIs, there should be something coming in iOS 9 as far as I recall.

Comment: @ShabarinathPabba You should be able to use the DKImagePickerController library for this: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

Comment: I can't recall iOS 9 having anything related to picking multiple images for UIImagePicker, anyways will take a look at the library. I wanted to stay away from using someone else's library, but I guess if thats the only way. I will have to I guess. Thanks.

Comment: That's true. My bad. Sure there were something about photos, but I must be mistaken. Can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];
        //... check if there is an image at this location and do something...
    }
}
```

You can also use `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:`

Comment: I'm having second thoughts about the approach... It's gonna mess up when the user scrolls, isn't it. I'd have to keep track of the selected photos, so I think I need to use to Assets Library to get multiple photos.